# How to get all analyzers rules in a solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio, roslyn-code-analysis, static-code-analysis, microsoft.codeanalysis

I have added some analyzer via NuGet in my solution.
How to get all added analyzer rules from NuGet references?
I need the ID (e.g. CA1001) and descriptions of all my enabled analyzers.

EDIT: I need some C# code to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the answer at [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/53965). Credits by jmarolf:

References:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Locator" Version="1.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.2" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" Version="3.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces" Version="3.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild" Version="3.9.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Build.Locator;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;

namespace AnalyzerReader
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Attempt to set the version of MSBuild.
            var instance = MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();

            Console.WriteLine($"Using MSBuild at '{instance.MSBuildPath}' to load projects.");

            using var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();

            // Print message for WorkspaceFailed event to help diagnosing project load failures.
            workspace.WorkspaceFailed += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Diagnostic.Message);

            var solutionPath = args[0];
            Console.WriteLine($"Loading solution '{solutionPath}'");

            // Attach progress reporter so we print projects as they are loaded.
            var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath, new ConsoleProgressReporter());
            Console.WriteLine($"Finished loading solution '{solutionPath}'");

            // Get all analyzers in the project
            var diagnosticDescriptors = solution.Projects
                .SelectMany(project => project.AnalyzerReferences)
                .SelectMany(analyzerReference => analyzerReference.GetAnalyzersForAllLanguages())
                .SelectMany(analyzer => analyzer.SupportedDiagnostics)
                .Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.Id);

            Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(DiagnosticDescriptor.Id),-15} {nameof(DiagnosticDescriptor.Title)}");
            foreach (var diagnosticDescriptor in diagnosticDescriptors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{diagnosticDescriptor.Id,-15} {diagnosticDescriptor.Title}");
            }
        }

        private class ConsoleProgressReporter : IProgress<ProjectLoadProgress>
        {
            public void Report(ProjectLoadProgress loadProgress)
            {
                var projectDisplay = Path.GetFileName(loadProgress.FilePath);
                if (loadProgress.TargetFramework != null)
                {
                    projectDisplay += $" ({loadProgress.TargetFramework})";
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"{loadProgress.Operation,-15} {loadProgress.ElapsedTime,-15:m\\:ss\\.fffffff} {projectDisplay}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can view the diagnostics produced by your project's analyzers in the "Dependencies" tree:

[image]

You can adjust the level (none, suggestion, warning, error, etc) via the context menu on these leaf nodes.

Alternatively, if you are using VS16.10 (released very recently) there is a new `.editorconfig` editor which includes a tab that shows all analyzers:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Drew!
But I need some C# code to do this.

Comment: If you can find the analyzer assemblies, you can probably walk them using reflection and pull out the individual analyzers that way.